# cannot import torch audio ' No audio backend is available.'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

```
import torchaudio
```

When I just try to import torch audio on Pycharm, I have this error

```
61: UserWarning: No audio backend is available.
```

warnings.warn('No audio backend is available.')

Comment: What is your question? What do you not understand about the error message?

Comment: I don't know what I have to do, I install correctly torch vision

Answer (score 53):

You need to install the audio file I/O backend. If Linux it's `Sox`, if Windows it's `SoundFile`

To check if you have one set run `str(torchaudio.get_audio_backend())` and if 'None' is the result then install the backend.

SoundFile for Windows `pip install soundfile`

Sox for Linux `pip install sox`

[Check out the PyTorch Audio Backend docs here](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/backend.html)

Comment: What fixed it for me was `pip uninstall PySoundFile && pip install PySoundFile`

Comment: In the latest versions of torchaudio (e.g., at least from 2.1.2 and greater) the `torchaudio.get_audio_backend()` function has been deprecated and you should use `torchaudio.list_audio_backends()` instead.

Comment: As noted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1819866/1289610), on Linux you may also need to install `libsox-dev`, e.g., on Ubuntu run `sudo apt install libsox-dev`.

Answer (score 7):

Just to put it out there.

I am using conda on windows 10. I tried to install PySoundFile from conda distribution `conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile` but it doesn't work.

Turns out we have to use `pip install PySoundFile`

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile` actually worked fine for me; I am using miniconda on Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

`conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile` worked for me on Windows 10 Anaconda also.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install libsox-dev
```

This worked for me on ubuntu