# How to solve RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri in python

Tags: python, pytorch, torchaudio

I want to work with audiofiles in pytorch.

If I try running this line: `metadata = torchaudio.info(SAMPLE_WAV_PATH)` i get the error message `RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri _assets\steam.wav and format None`

the internet told me to try `str(torchaudio.list_audio_backends())` to see if I have soundfile installed. It appears I don't, because it returns an empty list.

So I tried installing soundfile. Here is a list of commands i tried:

- `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch`
- `conda install -c conda-forge pysoundfile`
- `pip install soundfile`
- `pip install PySoundFile`

none of it made a difference. According to the anaconda navigator I have both pysoundfile and soundfile installed, but I still get the same error message. I searched for similar problems and found questions like this [cannot import torch audio ' No audio backend is available.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543843/cannot-import-torch-audio-no-audio-backend-is-available) But the only answeres there say I should install soundfile

If somebody got an idea whats wrong I would appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I am using windows 11

Comment: Did you try `pip uninstall PySoundFile && pip install PySoundFile`, I feel like one of the packages brought in the wrong version of a dependency and `pip` thought it was already installed.

Comment: I'd raise an eyebrow at that "and format none" and first confirm that (a) `_assets\steam.wav` even exists at all, and (b) is actually a .wav file. And probably not "in your filesystem" but when loaded as URI (e.g. confirm pytorch is looking in the correct base dir, etc), Because in absence of that, it's one of those "I bet it's actually trying to load a 404 server response as if it's an audio file".

Comment: @JonnyHenly I just tried `pip uninstall PySoundFile && pip install PySoundFile` and it didn't help

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In 'SAMPLE_WAV_PATH' stand '_assets\steam.wav' and yes it is there, I see it right here in my fileexplorer. Also even if the file would not be there, `str(torchaudio.list_audio_backends())` should still return something other than an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 11 machine with:

- ```text
  C:\Users\Foo>python3 --version
  Python 3.12.2
  ```
- ```text
  C:\Users\Foo>pip3 --version
  pip 24.0 from C:\Users\Foo\PathToPython312\site-packages\pip (python 3.12)
  ```
- ```text
  C:\Users\Foo>pip3 show torch torchvision torchaudio PySoundFile
  WARNING: Package(s) not found: torch torchvision torchaudio PySoundFile
  ```

  No previous installs of `torch`, `torchvision`, `torchaudio` or `PySoundFile`

---

I opened command prompt (not as administrator) and ran:

```text
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

Which installed:

```text
torch              2.2.1
torchaudio         2.2.1
torchvision        0.17.1
```

**Note:** several other dependency packages were installed along with the packages above.

I then ran `python3 ./test.py`:

```python
# ./test.py

import torchaudio
print(str(torchaudio.list_audio_backends()))
```

Which output an empty list:

```text
[]
```

So I then ran:

```text
pip3 install PySoundFile
```

Which installed:

```text
PySoundFile        0.9.0.post1
```

I then re-ran `python3 ./test.py` which output:

```text
['soundfile']
```

---

I suggest uninstalling all related packages:

```text
pip3 uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio PySoundFile
```

You'll probably also want to uninstall `soundfile`, since it's in the list of commands you tried.

I would then inspect the output of `pip3 list` and ensure the packages are no longer there. Then follow the steps I took above, in order, and see if you can get `['soundfile']` as output.

**Note:** I do not use anaconda, so if the steps above do not resolve your issue then I'd say there's a good chance that it's causing the problem.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, but I think your right that it has something to do with conda. I have tried uninstalling everything python related and I still find python realted folders. Anyway I am using google Colab now. No more worrying about any installations

Comment: Installing PySoundFile worked for me when I restarted my jupyterLab kernet sitting on top of a conda environment.