# How to solve RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri dataset/data/0.wav and format None

Tags: python, pytorch, sox, libsox

The Problem is if I try to run `metadata = torchaudio.info(path)` I get the error message `RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri dataset/data/0.wav and format None.` And if I run `print(str(torchaudio.list_audio_backends()))` it returns an empty list

I looked at both the documentation and similar questions, like those [How to solve RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78097861/how-to-solve-runtimeerror-couldnt-find-appropriate-backend-to-handle-uri-in-py/78103260#78103260), https://superuser.com/questions/1819222/how-to-install-sox-for-pytorch-audio/1819866#1819866 and [cannot import torch audio ' No audio backend is available.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543843/cannot-import-torch-audio-no-audio-backend-is-available). According to them I just need sox and libsox. None of the install commands from the answeres helped me.

I have installed both sox and libsox-dev. Here are the Versions:

- `pip show torchaudio` -> `... Version: 2.2.1 ...`
- `sox --version` -> `sox:      SoX v14.4.2`
- `ldd $(which sox) | grep libsox` -> `libsox.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsox.so.3`

I got no idea what's wrong and would appreciate any help.

Ps. I am using Ubuntu